# login.microsoftonline and restsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I tried a couple of things and this one works in postman
[image]

but in C# it doesn't work; it gives me a blank page
[image]

any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you stuck with RestSharp? I have working code for HttpClient.

Comment: nope, it can be anything :) 
@Crowcoder could you share?

Comment: Taking another look, what is probably tripping you up is that you are using GET instead of post. I wouldn't have thought it would work in Postman either but I guess it does.

Comment: OT: Prefer `var respose = ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with System.Net.HttpClient. I use JSON.NET to pluck the token out but you can parse the result any way you want:

```
//create a shared client somewhere convenient
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

...

```
string tokenurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token";
string appregClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string appregClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

HttpRequestMessage tknMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenurl);
Dictionary<string, string> tknBody = new Dictionary<string, string>{
    { "client_id", appregClientId },
    { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" },
    { "client_secret", appregClientSecret },
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tknBody);
tknMsg.Content = content;
var tknResponse = await client.SendAsync(tknMsg);

string tknResponseJson = await tknResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(tknResponseJson);

string accessTkn = (string)jobj["access_token"];
```